# Public and private keys generated via ECC

Tags: cryptography

Is there a possibility where two different users end up having same public and private keys generated via Ecliptic cure cryptography, or do we have a mechanism baked into the generator for preventing such a circumstance?

Comment: Yes it's possible, the mechanism used to combat this is the same mechanism used to combat adversaries guessing keys: probability theory. The entropy required of private keys for security purposes is more than enough to make the probability of duplication acceptably small. This all assumes that key generation is done correctly. If a randomness source is broken then one manifestation of this could be duplicate keys. This has actually happened in the past with RSA keys, where common primes were found in an enormous set of SSL certifcates.

Comment: What PresidentJamesK.Polk is this [The GCD strikes back to RSA in 2019 - Good randomness is the only solution?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76757/18298) and good randomness is the key to mitigate. We can talk about the probability with the birthday paradox if you provide the curve and the number of users ...